# How to implement asynchronous interdependent cancellable operations with actors?

Tags: future, actor, cancellation

I am quite new to the Actor model, that's why I think there are already established patterns addressing my common-looking scenario with such beautiful composable abstractions as actors and futures.

I have asynchronous operations with the following requirements:

- They use a legacy system by sending out a low-level request and then monitoring the state of the entity with polling. So the result of an actual operation is only available in a deferred way, requesters have to be notified when the observed state reaches the desired state.
- These operations can be issued only after some other operations are finished, for which they should wait in parallel.
- The operations can be cancelled. Of course, already issued low-level requests cannot be undone; cancellation means don't issue the actual operation after the operations which we depend on finished, and of course this has to be propagated recursively (if we wait for a dependency, and it has multiple pending operations, don't issue them).

I'm thinking in Futures: the first requirement can be solved with e.g. Akka's `map`/`flatMap`, the second with the `traverse` combinator without maintaining dependencies/dependents procedurally. But I can't think of a solution for *cancellation*; futures cannot be cancelled, and if composed, their components are not reachable. How to encapsulate "cancel the *current* operation" in a functional way? Does any of the Actor frameworks for Scala support this?

Comment: Why this question only has 1 up vote is beyond my comprehension. And after almost 3 years, there is still no good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use Listeners: https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/release-1.2/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/Listeners.scala

Make an Actor that uses Listeners to propagate the state of the polling to any and all listeners. Then you can use message-passing looping to reinitiate the polling.

```
class MyActor extends Actor with Listeners {

  override def preStart {
    self ! 'poll //Start looping on start
  }

  def receive = listenerManagement orElse {
    case 'poll => val result = pollYourExternalDude()
    gossip(result)
    self ! 'poll //Loop
  }
}
```

You can then stop the actor using either stop or sending the PoisonPill.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, meanwhile I studied the Akka docs more deeply and I edited the question accordingly. Futures and composing them are great but still do not solve cancellation. If I have to maintain listeners manually, I'll choose this way.

Comment: If you only use Futures you can have a Future that signals cancellation, so if it's completed it's cancelled, then check for that when you do your calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Guava's [ListenableFuture](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html)s support cancellation to a level when [bound together](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#chain%28com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) (but not when [combined from a collection](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList%28java.lang.Iterable%29)).